# Glitchy Mesh When Mirror Merging During Retopology

Tags: mirror, retopology, mirror-modifier

I'm trying to retopoligize my mesh. But my retopoligy mesh is acting glitchy where the mirror modifier meets. I have clipping turned on, so that my mirror modifier will connect. It seems to work ok on flat surfaces, but where there is a dip in the mesh, right where it needs to mirror, the mesh isn't connecting to the mirror, and its overlapping and acting glitchy.

**(See attached images and video Link)**

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks!

[Video on YouTube showing the issue here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WFZLFnFO1s)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the shrinkwrap modifier is moving your verts slightly off the center line.

The best, and simplest solution here it to move the shrinkwrap modifier below the mirror modifier in the modifier stack. The verts along the center line will then be merged, but may still be off center.

Any slightly off center vertices will need to be corrected when applying the shrinkwrap at the end of the retopology. The easiest way to do this is to select all the center line vertices and drag them back and forwards along the x axis only, so that they 'grab' onto the center line of the mirror modifier.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This fixed the issue. @Sazerac